# wp_get_attachment_image_src match smallest edge

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm trying to get the minimum image source that fills the given size.
`wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(180, 180))` gets the image which fits the size and not which **fills** it.

Is there any built-in possibility to get an image with minimum size?

I have an container DIV and want to put the posts thumbnail as background-image and want to the image to be `=>` sized.

Comment: Please try and rewrite your question it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Don't you know the difference between fit and fill? When you implement the function like above you will get an image that is e.g. `180x300` and not `108x180`. So these images will not **fill** but **fit** the given rect (`180x180`). Sorry, but I don't know how to make it more clear...